# Highcharts - heatmap : avoid 0 on resize chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using the heatmap chart from highcharts.

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid than the 0 value be displayed after resizing the chart.

Here an example :

http://jsfiddle.net/9ExnF/21/

`$`

Thanks for your help

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just use `dataLabels.formatter`:

```
            formatter: function() {
                if(this.point.value == 0) {
                     return '';   
                } else {
                     return this.point.value;   
                }
            }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9ExnF/22/